# Only insert row once with mysql (in one query)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables

```
series
    Id, Series_Id, Name, etc
genres
    Id, Name
series_genre
    Series_Id, Genre_Id
```

Now my problem is i want to use the unique identifiers of series and genre to store the series' genre in series_genre, like

```
INSERT INTO series_genre (Series_Id, Genre_Id) VALUES (1, 13)
```

Now i want to be able to only add the new row if the row doesn't already exist (to prevent duplicates). I tried to do it in one query, but couldn't figure it out, because one series should be able to have multiple genre assignments, so Series_Id and Genre_Id in series_genre can't be unique identifiers.

So to sum it up my question is: How to only insert a row, if a row with the same values doesn't already exists, in one query!? Thanks in advance!

Comment: query the table of mysql to see if the row is available id yes flag error if no create the row.

Comment: Series_id and genre_id can form a unique combined key.

Answer (score 1):

First, let the database validate the data, so create a unique constraint/index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_series_genre_2 ON series_genre(series_id, genre_id);
```

Then to ignore duplicates, I recommend `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`:

```
INSERT INTO series_genre (Series_Id, Genre_Id)
    VALUES (1, 13)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Series_Id = VALUES(Series_Id);
```

Why do I prefer this over `INSERT IGNORE`?  For two reasons.  First, there is no performance penalty because the record does not actually change.  (This is very important and not true in all databases when an update does not change the data.)

Second, this specifically only ignores errors when unique key violations occur.  `INSERT IGNORE` can ignore other errors that you might want to catch.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT ... SELECT` might work out here.

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO series_genre (Series_Id, Genre_Id) 
SELECT 
 1, 13 
FROM 
 DAUL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 
   1 
  FROM 
    series_genre
  WHERE
     Series_Id = 1
   AND 
     Genre_Id = 13   
)
```